# Using SSIS, can I extract data from a flat file to an existing table that is partially populated?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, flat-file

I have a table that consists of 4 columns: c1 c2 c3 c4. c1 has usable data c2-4 are NULL.

Can I use a flat file to extract relational data for c1? I am new so I am hoping I am explaining that properly.

ex)

```
c1   c2
mike null
```

I want to extract the last name into c2

Comment: Yes, instead of an OLEDB Destination, you would use an EXECUTE SQL as a destination and do an UPDATE in the SQL.   Or a MERGE if you want to also insert new rows.

Comment: Given a delimited input file that contains `mike|wiggins` the question is can I use SSIS to add wiggins into the existing record?

Comment: Yes @billinkc can I use ssis to add relational data an existing record